# Remove a Custom Dialog Windows (PyGTK + Quickly)

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk, glade, dialog

Do Quickly have a **remove dialog** command?

*Like:* `quickly remove dialog <dialog-name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No ,

quickly did'nt included command for removimg added dialogs , you should do it manually .ie delete python file and ui file generated by quickly add dialog command

Comment: Ok.. so the add command, only adds the myDialog.ui and myDialog.xml file in the data/ui folder and then myDialog.py and myDialog.pyc in the root/projectname/ folder? or do I need to delete more